# Configure output cache per user mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a user specific dashboard.  The dashboard will only change daily, I want to use `MVC's` `OutputCache`.  Is there any way to configure the caching per user and to expire when the request is a new day?

I have researched this and found you can extend the `OutputCache` attribute to dynamically set your duration however how can I configure this per user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your `Web.config`:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="Dashboard" duration="86400" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="User" location="Server" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

In your `Controller`/`Action`:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile="Dashboard")]
public class DashboardController { ...}
```

Then in your `Global.asax`:

```
//string arg filled with the value of "varyByCustom" in your web.config
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "User")
        {
        // depends on your authentication mechanism
        return "User=" + context.User.Identity.Name;
        //return "User=" + context.Session.SessionID;
        }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
}
```

In essence, `GetVaryByCustomString` lets you write a custom method to determine whether there will be a Cache `hit/miss`.

Comment: does this same concept work with DevTrends DonutCaching?

Comment: Didn't try it but since they do provide a `VaryByCustom` mechanism as well. I assume the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in web.config,

```
<system.web>
 ...........
 ...........
 <caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="UserCache" duration="1440" varyByParam="UserID" enabled="true" location="Client"/>
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```