# What should I use instead of session?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project which I need to build a list of menus according with the profile of the logged user. But, currently I have to build this list each time the page is loaded and this is not too good for my project.

What I want to do is get this list only when the user logs in and use it each time that I need it. My idea is store this list in the `Session` when the user logs in. But I know the session isn't a good practice.

I've tried to use the session, cookie and `OutputCache` in `ActionResult` but only the session works.

Is there a way to store my list in a "global variable", or something like that, and use it always I need it?

Comment: That's exactly what `Session` is.

Comment: Using the Session is not necessarily wrong in all cases, but it can be misused. This situation sounds like what the session is indeed intended for, so use it.

Comment: Could also use a cookie...if the menu changes destroy the cookie and recreate it.

Comment: Yes, but my application has more than 10k users per day and I think the Session will "weight" the server and the AppPool (IIS)... It'll be the only Session that I'd use on project... I'm afraid to use and compromising performance.

Comment: DLeh is right. Also, session is a mechanism - but you can use different session providers for your application. Sessions can be stored in Redis database, SQL database, Mongo database, files, memory and so on. You decide what you need. It is strange that OutputCache did not work for you, probably there was an error in configuration. As for me, it should work as well, and probably it is easier to use than session management.

Comment: however you cache it, it will take the same amount of memory, so storing it in a "global variable" would have the same effect.

Comment: @JonH Yes I tried it, but my list of menus has almost 50 itens and almost 10 properties...

Comment: might try no sql database like Redis, it`s fast and reliable, and used as a rapid exchange storage often.

Comment: @Vladimir Yeah, I think I'll try the Redis.

Comment: What about retrieving it asynchronously and persisting it to either a cookie or the local storage (if its html5 complaint)? That will offload everything but the build of the structure which you have to do once anyway. It also allows the rest of your page to load without having to wait on the menu which can be added as soon as its available.

Comment: @PavelMorshenyuk the OutputCache works, but my ActionResult was the same for all users, independently of the user and his profile (menu access).

Comment: Check this question about configuring output cache on per user basis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080416/configure-output-cache-per-user-mvc

Comment: @Igor It sounds good, I'm not using html5 because the most of the computers are too old and they won't run the application.

Comment: @PavelMorshenyuk I'll try it again, I guess I didn't configure correctly the webconfig, I think so... Do u think the OutputCache is better than Session (or something like that)? One more thing, If my user loggoff the application, automatically the OutputCache will be clean?

Comment: I think the output cache can be useful in your case. You can enable output cache on server and client side. Most browsers will happily cache your json responses in the local storage - so it will almost free to your server resources to use such cache. At the same time you should enable cache for server-side, you can set the expiration time for the cache so that you store only information for currently active users, instead of loading menus for all 10k users to the third-part database.

Comment: @PavelMorshenyuk Nice. Thank you. I'll try it. The OutputCache will be called only when the user loggin the application, right?

Comment: @PavelMorshenyuk I've tried OutputCache but my Action is a ChildAction and then didn't work it =/

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two options for you problem.

1. Use Session object for each user.
   or
2. Use Caching mechanism - If you have implemented some caching mechanism in you application, you can create one object per one user storing the navigation menu(Something like Redis, AppFabric or .NET caching).

Object related to the menu should be create only one time for the user(You can create it during the login).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a database storing the built list when profiles are created/changed (could be something as simple as a JSON string?) referenced by the user id.

Simply then a case of selecting this with a single user id value - a simple data type can get a complex datatype.

Comment: I already created a table to store the menus. But currently each request I have to get this menus from the database (SQL Server) and this is what I don't wanna do it.

Comment: Sorry, yes on re-reading you build on login and serve on pages for that login session. So SESSION is exactly what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help.

To solve my issue, I had to use the **Session**. Why? Because each user has his own '(SidebarViewModel)Session["sidebar"]' which contains all specific menus, name, ids and avatar.

I've tried to use the "OutputCache" (My own attribute class), but as my menu is a ChildAction I couldn't clear my cache on logoff and it's not so good to the user who can change his own avatar when he wants to. I also tried to use the Application but it was almost the same case of the Sessions.

PS: I don't like the Sessions, but I think it's the best way for now.